# I wrote that code in Dr Racket, but I don´t know why but my last Test is not working. Anyone maybe know why?

Tags: scheme, racket

I wrote that code in Dr Racket, I had to evaluate all items withe the goal to choose which are better to be bought. Now I think I might be fished, but now I have a problem with the last Test, the one in the last line in the Code. Somehow it´s not wiring, anyone maybe know what is wrong with my code. Maybe I´m too much in it, but I can not find my mistake.

For a answer I would be really thankful.

```
    (define-struct item (name volume yield typical))

;; volume of a standard european container in m^3
(define container-volume 78.6)

;; sample items
(define strong-beer (make-item "Strong Beer" 15 8372 7))
(define cheap-beer (make-item "Cheap Beer" 21 4562 2))
(define good-beer (make-item "Good Beer" 7 5113 9))
(define pretzels (make-item "German Style Pretzels" 7 9280 5))
(define weisswurst (make-item "Weisswurst" 8 7254 10))
(define sweet-mustard (make-item "Sweet Mustard" 1 265 6))
(define haxen (make-item "Haxen" 11 3500 7))
(define sauerkraut (make-item "Sauerkraut" 7 4012 3))
(define bavarian-leberkaes (make-item "Bavarian Leberkaes" 6 1952 6))
(define schnitzel (make-item "Schnitzel" 16 8068 2))
(define obatzda (make-item "Obatzda" 3 3025 8))
(define dumplings (make-item "Dumplings" 8 1234 3))
(define dirndl (make-item "Dirndl" 12 8069 9))

;; all items
(define all-stuff
  (list strong-beer cheap-beer good-beer pretzels weisswurst sweet-mustard
        haxen sauerkraut bavarian-leberkaes schnitzel obatzda dumplings dirndl))


;;Code:
(define (evaluate-item-sum item)
  (foldr (lambda (item sum) (+ (item-volume item) sum)) 0 item)
  )

;;Test:
(check-expect (evaluate-item-sum all-stuff) 122)
(check-expect (evaluate-item-sum (list haxen dirndl)) 23)

;;===============================================================================


;;Code:
(define (choose-items items container-volume)
  (cond
    ((empty? items) empty)
    ((cons? items)
     (local (
             (define first-volume (item-volume (first items))))
             (if (> first-volume container-volume)
             (choose-items (rest items) container-volume)
             (local (
                     (define choice1 (choose-items (rest items) container-volume))
                     (define choice2
                       (cons (first items)
                             (choose-items (rest items) (- container-volume first-volume)))))
               (if (> (evaluate-item-sum choice1) (evaluate-item-sum choice2))
                   choice1
                   choice2)))))))



;; Tests
(check-expect (choose-items all-stuff 50) (list haxen dirndl))
```

Comment: You need to explain what `choose-items` is supposed to do. It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: It consumes a list of the items, in the combination that is best for us.

Comment: Define "best". It's hard to see if your code has a bug in it if there's no definition of what the correct behaviour is. :-)

Comment: Found now my Problem and have it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the value 50 in your call to `choose-items`, but I guess it should be 23. And then, there's a second combination that fits (StrongBeer GoodBeer Mustard), so to get the result you want you'd have to move Haxen and Dirndl to the front of your list `all-stuff` so that these get found first. With that modified list and the value 23 the last test passes:

```
(define all-stuff
  (list haxen dirndl strong-beer cheap-beer good-beer pretzels weisswurst sweet-mustard
         sauerkraut bavarian-leberkaes schnitzel obatzda dumplings ))
```

and

```
(check-expect (choose-items all-stuff 23) (list haxen dirndl))
```